# Which IP address do I enter at dlinkddns.com?

Tags: dynamic-dns

I am trying to set up DDNS in my router to enable a static IP address. Standard procedure, should not be a hassle really, but I am facing troubles at dlinkddns.com. Which "New IP address" does it want me to enter into the box as depicted below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well I was being silly... It was as simple as to enter the same Browser IP Adress mentioned in the field above... The vague error message it gave me when doing so apparently meant that I had entered a *hostname* that was already in use... By entering a more unique hostname, the problem got solved.